# How to do a many to many field in Pocketbase

Tags: backend, pocketbase

I have a database with users and products.

My products have a relation field relating to the users so i can get the usernames and such via

`const product = await pb.collection('products').getOne(id, { expand: "user" })`

How would I do the same for users, and getting all products that a user has?
Should i add a relation field to my users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from one of the devs.

If you have many users then you should:

```
const products = await pb.collection("products").getFullList(200, { filter: `user = "${userId}"` })
```

and if you only have 1:

```
const user = await pb.collection("user").getOne("USER_ID", { expand: "products(user)") })
```